# How to rewrite below code using streams in java8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
private void enrichWithFieldList(String desc, String value, List<Data> dataList, List<Field> fieldList) {
        int index = 1;
        for(Data data : dataList){
            if(!"english".equals(data.getCode())){
                createFieldList(desc+index, data.getCode(), fieldList);
                createFieldList(value+index++, data.getValue(), fieldList);
            }
        }
    }

private void createFieldList(String fieldName, String fieldValue, List<Field> fieldList) {
        Field customField = new Field();
        customField.setName(fieldName);
        customField.setValue(fieldValue);
        fieldList.add(customField);
}
```

Can anybody tell me how to rewrite the above code using Java8 streams?

Comment: Given you have a mutable variable this is not really suitable as a stream. Are you sure you want a list of fields instead of a Map. btw it's a bad idea to use the name of a common class.

Comment: Thanks @PeterLawrey for the quick reply, Its ok if it is a map instead of list

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell your trying to come up with a new list of fields based on your data list. If so, probably best to create that directly from a stream rather than add to a list passed into your method.

Something like the following:

```
private List<Field> makeEnrichedFieldList(String desc, String value, List<Data> dataList) {
    return IntStream.range(0, dataList.size())
        .filter(i -> !dataList.get(i).getCode().equals("english"))
        .boxed ()
        .flatMap(i -> Stream.of(new Field(desc + i + 1, dataList.get(i).getCode()),
                                new Field(value + i + 1, dataList.get(i).getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: ```dataList.get(1)```?  ```desc + i + 1```? unknown Field constructor.

Comment: `dataList.get(1)` surely should be `dataList.get(i)`. Besides that, you are performing unnecessary boxing and unboxing operations. Just move the `.boxed()` invocation *after* the `.filter(…)` operation, right before `flatMap`, and the filtering can work without the need to unbox an `Integer` for each stream element. Further, only the elements which pass the filter will get boxed then.

Answer (score 2):

You can write this, though it's perhaps more complicated.

```
private List<Field> enrichWithFieldList(String desc, String value, List<Data> dataList) {
    int[] index = { 1 };
    return dataList.stream()
                   .filter(d -> !"english".equals(d.getCode())
                   .flatMap(d -> Stream.of(new Field(desc+index[0], data.getCode()), 
                                           new Field(value+index[0]++, data.getValue())))
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
 }
```

Instead of using `desc` and `value` I suggest just using a map of code to value.

If you can use a Map, I suggest doing.

```
private Map<String, String> asMap(Collection<Data> data) {
    return data.stream()
               .filter(d -> !"english".equals(d.getCode())
               .collect(Collectors.toMap(Data:getCode, Data:getValue));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Peter Lawrey for your post, but Field class is Jaxb generated class which dont have constructor, in that case how can I set properties, also in my requirement I want to pass List<Field> as a parameter and need to  add each Field object to this list

Comment: @NareshBandaru You can create helper method which call the default constructor and the setters like the one you have above.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are saying that you can’t change the `Field` class to add a constructor, you should keep your factory method, but you should clean it up by letting it create the instance without dealing with `List`s:

```
private Field createField(String fieldName, String fieldValue) {
    Field customField = new Field();
    customField.setName(fieldName);
    customField.setValue(fieldValue);
    return customField;
}
```

Then, [sprinter’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34388774/2711488) already guides to the right solution. If you need the index, the solution is to use an `IntStream` of indices and map them to the `List` elements rather than streaming over the list and trying to reconstitute the index. Then, `flatMap` is the right operation for mapping an element to two elements. Your condition may be implemented either, as a `filter` operation before the `flatMap` or get integrated into the `flatMap` operation which may map to an empty stream (or just `null`) if the condition isn’t fulfilled.

There is only one catch. The current API lacks an `IntStream.flatMapToObj(…)` operation. A simple workaround is to use `boxed().flatMap(…)`, like in sprinter’s answer, which has the disadvantage of boxing overhead, or a `mapToObj(…).flatMap(t->t)` which maps the `int` values to `Stream`s object first and then does the flattening on `Stream` rather than `IntStream`:

```
private void enrichWithFieldList(
             String desc, String value, List<Data> dataList, List<Field> fieldList) {
    List<Field> collected=IntStream.rangeClosed(1, dataList.size())
        .filter(index -> !"english".equals(dataList.get(index-1).getCode()))
        .mapToObj(index -> {
            Data data=dataList.get(index-1);
            return Stream.of(createField(desc+index, data.getCode()),
                             createField(value+index, data.getValue()));
        }).flatMap(t->t)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    fieldList.addAll(collected);
}
```

This doesn’t box `int`s into `Integer` objects, but has the slight disadvantage of invoking `dataList.get(index-1)` twice for elements that pass the filter. As said, an alternative is to fuse `filter` and `flatMap`:

```
private void enrichWithFieldList(
             String desc, String value, List<Data> dataList, List<Field> fieldList) {
    List<Field> collected=IntStream.rangeClosed(1, dataList.size())
        .mapToObj(index -> {
            Data data=dataList.get(index-1);
            return "english".equals(data.getCode())? null:
                Stream.of(createField(desc+index, data.getCode()),
                          createField(value+index, data.getValue()));
        }).flatMap(t->t)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    fieldList.addAll(collected);
}
```

But there is another alternative. Since in this case, the intermediate steps don’t really simplify the stream code, we may merge them into the `collect` operation without loosing readability:

```
private void enrichWithFieldList(
             String desc, String value, List<Data> dataList, List<Field> fieldList) {
    List<Field> collected=IntStream.rangeClosed(1, dataList.size())
        .collect(ArrayList::new, (list, index) -> {
            Data data=dataList.get(index-1);
            if(!"english".equals(data.getCode())) {
                list.add(createField(desc+index, data.getCode()));
                list.add(createField(value+index, data.getValue()));
            }
        }, List::addAll);
    fieldList.addAll(collected);
}
```

Then we don’t have a transition from `IntStream` to `Stream` at all.

But note that an ordinary loop may still look simpler than that. Unless you have rather large lists to process and are thinking about processing them in parallel, the stream API isn’t a win here.